# tabmenu items dont change and html page doesnt include correctly

Tags: html, jsf-2, primefaces

i am working on dynamic page. want to include a xhtml page to main xhtml page with tabmenu. when i run code always same page include main page. tabs dont work anoymore.

main html.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" 
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <title>İstatistik</title>
        </f:facet>
    </h:head>
    <body>
    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="north"  style="font-size: 12px!important" >
            <p:tabMenu id="tabmenu1" activeIndex="#{turnPage.index}"  >
                <p:menuitem value="Genel" outcome="main"  actionListener="#{turnPage.actionEventPage(e, 0)}" update="mainpanel" />
                <p:menuitem value="Demografik Göstergeler" outcome="main"  actionListener="#{turnPage.actionEventPage(e, 1)}" update="mainpanel" />
                <p:menuitem value="Mortalite ve Mobidite" outcome="main" actionListener="#{turnPage.actionEventPage(e, 2)}" update="mainpanel" />
                <p:menuitem value="Risk Faktörleri" outcome="main" actionListener="#{turnPage.actionEventPage(e, 3)}" update="mainpanel" />
                <p:menuitem value="Bağışıklama Anne/çocuk" outcome="main" actionListener="#{turnPage.actionEventPage(e, 4)}" update="mainpanel" />
                <p:menuitem value="Sağlık Kurumları" outcome="main" actionListener="#{turnPage.actionEventPage(e, 5)}" update="mainpanel" />
            </p:tabMenu>
        </p:layoutUnit>  
        <p:layoutUnit  position="center">
            <p:outputPanel id="mainpanel"  >
                <h:form>
                    <ui:include src="#{turnPage.pathpage}"/>
                </h:form>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:layoutUnit>      
    </p:layout>
</body>
```

}

and here is my bean.

{

```
private int index;
private String pathpage;

public void setPathpage(String pathpage) {
    this.pathpage = pathpage;
}

public String getPathpage() {
    return pathpage;
}

public void setIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
}

public int getIndex() {
    return index;
}

public void actionEventPage(ActionEvent e, int index){

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            pathpage =  "forms/genel.xhtml";
            break;
        case 1:
            pathpage =  "forms/demografi.xhtml";
            break;
        case 2:
            pathpage =  "forms/mortalite.xhtml";
            break;
        case 3:
            pathpage =  "forms/riskfaktor.xhtml";
            break; 
        case 4:
            pathpage =  "forms/bagisiklama.xhtml";
            break;
        case 5:
            pathpage =  "forms/saglikkurum.xhtml";
            break;
```

Comment: its not duplicate. actually i can include first page but tabmenu item index doesnt change when i choose any tab and choosen page doesnt include.

Comment: If you follow the kickoff example in the duplicate, it will.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the ActionEvent param from actionEventPage method.
On xhtml:

```
#{turnPage.actionEventPage(5)}
```

On bean:

```
public void actionEventPage(int index)...
```

Comment: i've already done this solution. actually my problem is about tabmenu. when first choose include html but second or third choose doesnt work. still include first page on the screen.